# Rotating a 3D mesh in direct x

Tags: c++, directx

I have inhereted a Direct x project which I am trying to improve. The problem I am having is that I have 2 meshes and I want to move one independent of the other. at the moment I can manipulate the world matrix simply enough, but I am unable to rotate an indervidual mesh.

```
 V( g_MeshLeftWing.Create( pd3dDevice, L"Media\\Wing\\Wing.sdkmesh", true));
```

loades the mesh and later it is rendered

```
renderMesh(pd3dDevice, &g_MeshLeftWing );
```

Is there a way I can rotate the mesh. I tried transforming it using a matirx with no success?

```
g_MeshLeftWing.TransformMesh(&matLeftWingWorld,0);
```

any help would be great

Comment: The problem could lie everywhere, you should try to add some more information. Normally you can set a different worldmatrix for each mesh and render it, but i don't know how your framework works. What matrix does it use for rendering, how can it be manipulated, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you appear to be loading a ".sdkmesh" file. It was documented heavily in the DirectX SDK that  ".sdkmesh" was made for the SDK and should not be used as an actual mesh loading/drawing solution.

Therefore I would advise you start looking at alternative means to load and draw your model, not only will that give you a greater understanding of DirectX, but it should ultimately answer your question in the long run!